# delay output one by one php

Tags: php, ajax

In this code , it have 5 output .

how to delay output like

show output 1 -delay 1 sec.-
and then show output 2 -delay 1 sec.- 
and then show output 3 -delay 1 sec.- 
and then show output 4 -delay 1 sec.- 
and then show output 5 -delay 1 sec.-

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM test_grid order by id Limit $i,1 ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
    $objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
    echo nl2br($objResult["text"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/sleep and realize that you can NOT control with 100% reliability how things get sent from your server to the client and displayed.

Comment: This sounds like a task for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this the best way, please refer to [JavaScript Timing Events.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The sleep command might work, but as Marc B said it might not work on some or all servers.

I personally agree with Matt Ball on this one. It's a job for javascript using either setTimeout (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) or setInterval (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)